# Fading out a Cocoa window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

Hello I am wondering if there is a way to animate a window in objective-c using core-animation or quartz.  I would like to fade out a window when I close it.  My OSX operating system is Tiger.

**Edit:** Is it possible to do the same with an applescript application in Xcode by somehow calling a method from objective-c or another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[NSViewAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSViewAnimation_Class/), despite its name, works on windows as well. There's [a key you can use to perform fade-out animations](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSViewAnimation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSViewAnimationEffectKey).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will look into it shortly

Answer (score 0):

Core Animation was added to OS X with Leopard. It's the same API as on the iPhone. There are a multitude of iPhone Core Animation tutorials on the web that should get you started.

[This](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/03/15/core-animation-tutorial-dashboard-effect/) tutorial is OS X specific and shows multiple animation types, including fading.

Comment: Core Animation was added in Leopard, not Snow Leopard.